# Two-way bind does not work if the model is something like ng-model="record.name" for Kendo UI controls

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a problem with Kendo UI controls

My HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="record.name" kendo-numeric-text-box />
 <input type="text" ng-model="record.name"> </input>
 <button ng-click="resetRecord()" >test bind</button>
```

My test.js

```
$scope.record ={};
$scope.resetRecord= function(){
        $scope.record = {};
    }
```

Well, when I execute the function `resetRecord` just the standard input clear, the kendo ui input does not clear, I've tried `$scope.record =null` and it does not work either.

if I change to code below, it works, but I need it works like above

```
$scope.resetRecord= function(){
        $scope.record. name = null;
    }
```

it happens with all input Kendo UI, not just kendo-numeric-text-box

if there is a way to iterate with `record` object, discovering all the "properties", such as **name** it will work for me.

My intention is just have one controller for all CRUD screen of the system, I wouldn't like to write one controller with model definition for each entity of the system.
is it a bug?

**UPDATED - SOLVED**

Solution 1 
  As runTarm said in solution 2.

```
for (prop in $scope.model.record) {
            $scope.model.record[prop]='';
        }
```

Solution 2
   Just add the attribute `k-rebind` to the Kendo UI controls and it will update it's content according `ng-model`.

```
input type="text" ng-model="record.name" k-rebind="record.name" kendo-numeric-text-box />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a common issue due to the *Prototypal Inheritance* characteristic of JavaScript Object. I would recommend reading [Understanding-Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more detail.

You could avoid the problem by storing the `record` in another object, instead of in `$scope` directly. For example:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.record = {};
$scope.resetRecord = function() {
  $scope.model.record = {};
}
```

Also change your `ng-model`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.record.name" kendo-numeric-text-box />
<input type="text" ng-model="model.record.name"> </input>
<button ng-click="resetRecord()" >test bind</button>
```

Or if you wouldn't want to add the extra `model.`, an alternative solution is what you have mentioned.

You could iterate over object's properties and delete them all like this:

```
for (prop in $scope.record) {
  delete $scope.record[prop];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: runTarm, the solution 1 didn't work, the solution 2 worked with a bit change, instead use delete I just set the prop to ''. I discovered anothe rsolution, just use the attribute k-rebind="propertyName", if the property changes the Kendo Controls rebind its value. I'm going to edit the question with your solution and mine.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I see, thanks for the update about `k-rebind`.